# Displaying ArrayLists with fields removed

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a project in which my program is to read from a text file certain information about employees (ID, first and last name, date available, annual salary, etc.)
I have created an employee class, along with the `hashCode` and `equals` methods as well as all the getters, setters, variable declarations and whatnot.
The problem I'm having is in the main class.  Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Employee> db = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("employeeDB.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("employeeDB.txt"));
    while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fin.nextLine();
        String[] fields = line.split(",", 0);
        Employee emp = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]), fields[1],
                fields[2], fields[3], fields[4], Integer.parseInt(fields[5]),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[6]), fields[7], fields[8],
                Double.parseDouble(fields[9]), fields[10]);
        db.add(emp);
    }

    listAllEmployee(db);
    System.out.println("");
    listAllEmployeeEidAndName(db);

}
public static void listAllEmployee(ArrayList<Employee> list) {
    System.out.println("List all employees:");
    for (Employee emp : list) {
        System.out.println(emp);
    }
}

public static void listAllEmployeeEidAndName(ArrayList<Employee> list) {
    System.out.println("List all empoyee eid and name:");
    for (Employee emp : list) {
        System.out.println("Employee{eid=" + emp.getEid()
                + ", firstName=" + emp.getFirstName()
                + ", lastName=" + emp.getLastName());
    }
}

public static void listEmployeeByField(ArrayList<Employee> list,
        int field) {
    }
```

I am unsure of how to do that last method.  The only idea I had was to write an enormous switch statement in a similar way that I did for the `listAllEmployeeEidAndName` method, but that seems impractical.

Is there a way to have it remove fields and only display the one that is given when the `listEmployeeByField` method is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a method like this to `Employee`

```
public String selectField(int... fields) {
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("Employee{");
    if (fields.length == 0) {
        strb.append("No fields selected ");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            switch(fields[i]) {
                case 0: strb.append("eid=" + id + ","); break;
                case 1: strb.append("firstName=" + firstName + ","); break;
                //... and so on
                default: strb.append("-->Field " + fields[i] + " doesn't exist<--");  
            }
        }
    }
    strb.replace(strb.length() - 1, strb.length(), "}");
    return strb.toString();
}
```

and write your method like this:

```
public static void listAllEmployeeByField(List<Employee> list, int... fields) {
    System.out.println("Listin all empoyee by fields "+ Arrays.toString(fields) + ":");
    for (Employee emp : list) {
        System.out.println(emp.selectField(fields));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map that maps a field to a list of employees. Something like:

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Employee>>();

for(Employee e : list)
{
   if(e.containsKey(e.getField())
   {
      List<Employee> list = map.get(e.getField());
      list.add(e);
      map.put(e.getField(), list);
   }
   else
   {
      List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>()l
      list.add(e);
      map.put(e.getField(), list);
   }
}
```

At the end you could then iterate through the map's keys and print out all the employees by field.

Answer (score 0):

By field I see you are referring the properties like id, name, etc... You can try this as you have figured out that you'll need to use a switch, that's correct.

```
public static void listEmployeeByField(ArrayList<Employee> list, int field) {
        for(Employee e : list) {
            switch(field) {
                case 0: System.out.println(e.getId());
                        break;
                case 1: System.out.println(e.getFirstName());
                        break;
                case 2: System.out.println(e.getLastName());
                        break;
                // .... and so on
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to store an array of strings - fields[] in your Employee class where value at the location 'field' is the name of the field(string). For example, say "ID" is a field stored at 0 and "Name" is a field stored at location 1, then your fields array would look something like this in memory:

fields = {"Id","Name", ...... ,}

Then all you need to do is print the string at the correct location :

public static void listEmployeeByField(ArrayList list, int field) 
   {

```
    for (Employee emp : list) 
    System.out.println(emp.fields[field]);
```

}

You can construct this array at the same time as you assign values to other members of the class by passing in the string array 'fields' in your main to the class constructor.